# with flask, is it bad to use multiprocessing.Process to handle concurrent requests?

Tags: python, flask

The flask python server can handle by default only one connection at a time.

By using multiprocessing.Process() one can spawn work tasks for every request. Each request takes some time for example to query a database.

question 1.
Why is it bad and why a WSGI server would be recommended and superior?

question 2.
It works with multiprocessing.Process(). Maybe it is not structured. But what real problem can happen in the future?

Comment: My main reason to use GUnicorn instead of building something myself is that it is so much easier.  However, there are other reasons, e.g. spawning a new process for each process as you suggest would be incredibly inefficient, so you would need to implement something more elaborate.

Comment: If one wants to reuse the pymongo connection and not create a new one for each request, is it possible using a WSGI server? (example please)

Comment: You can create a connection when the process starts.  In Flask, you can use the [application context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#context-usage).

Comment: Please clarify. It seems to me that if I create a connection when the flask process start, the started process is already a child of the WSGI server. The connection resource cannot be shared accross different WSGI "children".

Comment: You asked how to avoid having to create a new pymongo connection for each request, not how to share it among multiple GUnicorn workers.  I think the latter might be possible as well, but I'm pretty sure you don't want to do this – you would need a way for the individual workers to lock the connection, and I can't see what you would gain.  Having a single connection per worker seems a lot more reasonable.

Comment: There are several stack overflow threads that recommend not to create a new database connection for each query.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625003/php-mysql-create-new-connection-for-each-query

The database is strained by opening connections. The logs are strained also. There is a latency that is not negligible. I am very interested to know how to do it with gunicord or any WSGI server. I t seems the SWGI server spawns children that cannot share a connection.

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested a solution that only creates one connection per worker, not one per request.

Comment: AH thanks. I just realize the nuance of per worker or per request. Per worker resources will remain for the next request. I thought wrongly that the WSGI was resetting the whole flask app at every request.

Answer (score 1):

By the method of using `multiprocess` library and attempting concurrent processes for requests you risk limiting the concurrency to maximum of number of cores the machine CPU has. This is loosely equivalent to using `--workers` flag with something like `gunicorn` and providing maximum number of cores available for the guincorn server to run. While sure one can write the required logic to provide CPU time to each connection it seems like a lot of effort when WSGI frameworks exists to do exactly that. I'd suggest you going through [**Settings**](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html) and [**Design**](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html) documentation of **GUnicorn** to obtain an even better clarity on your situation.